# Can Someone explain what this error is caused by and how I am able to fix it?

Tags: errors

The aforementioned error is given below.
The error occurs when attempting to compile a document in LaTex

Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It looks like your editor cannot find the compiler.  Which editor are you using?  How did you install TeX?  Which operating system are you using?

Comment: check [previous posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Error+%3A+could+not+start+the+command+%3A+pdflatex+-synctex%3D1+-interaction%3Dnonstopmode+hasaccepted%3Ayes)